DC/DC controller identification help
The device in question is an inline PoE board from a Hikvision camera. There is a TPS2376-H PD controller and after it is a DC/DC controller in SOIC-8 package I cannot identify and for which I ask for help. The IC uses an integrated transistor. Marking code is A0F6WA. Frequency seems around 132Khz (not sure if it is exact). Specifics to the pinout:

1 is GND;
2 - resistor to pin 1, current sense (observed with the scope); probably transistor source as well;
3 - unknown;
4 - transistor output to transformer primary (open drain);
5 - unknown;
6 - seems to be power. Auxiliary winding is also fed here through a diode, a resistor and a capacitor;
7 - unknown;
8 - unknown.

As to the unknown pins - have not yet have the chance to properly investigate. Pin 7 seems (speculating) to have a resistor and a capacitor - probably a frequency setting.
The IC uses primary side regulation - no opto feedback. Not sure whether it uses the auxiliary winding for the purpose or the primary one.
Thanks!

Please post pictures.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2376-h.pdf?ts=1735658437064&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F

Why do U need this? failure ? or understanding?  similar https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2897754.pdf
